# Compute function values using Lagrange polynomials for ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

Given the Lagrange Basis Functions:

[image]

And an ODE of the form:

[image]

[image]

The lagrange interpolation states that:

[image]

Moreover:

[image]

I read that the last expression allows to build a algebraic equation system of N equations by N variables and that in turn should allow computing the function evaluated at those $x(t_j)$ and then use those to determine the interpolation function.

Whenever I try to do this approach I always end up with a system whose solutions do not match with the analytical answer.

Consider this example:

$$\dot{x} = -x + t$$
$$x(0) = 5$$
$$t_0 = 0, t_1 = 1, t_2 = 2$$

The analytical solution is:

$$x(t) = t - 1 + 6\cdot e^{-t}$$

Which yield:
$$x(t_0) = 5, x(t_1) \approx 2.20, x(t_2) \approx 4.04$$

Whereas when using the formula above I get:
$$\hat{x}(t_0) = 5, \hat{x}(t_1) \approx 2.769, \hat{x}(t_2) \approx 3.076$$

The error is too big to be some machine error or truncation error.

Am I missing something? Is there any bibliography with a step by step example to check if I am using the correct procedure (I couldn't find anything googling)?

Comment: Please use mathjax. Is the general aim for fixed-step multi-step methods or for variable step sizes? With the rather large step size $1$, large errors are to be expected. For a second order method, the bootstrap process should also be at least second order, as far as I can see you used a first order step.

Comment: I would expect big error but doesn't lagrange polynomial guarantees exact match on $t_i$?

Comment: How, exactly, did you compute your numerical values? Separately computing $x_1$ via the trapezoidal method and treating the simultaneous computation of $x_1,x_2$ as collocation method give different results from the ones you provide. To solve the implicit system as presented would result in $N+1$ equations, but $x_1,...x_N$ are only $N$ free variables, so what is the additional degree of freedom?

Comment: With the collocation approach I get $[x_1,x_2]=[2.57142857,\, 1.85714286] $ where the exact values would be $[x(1),x(2)]=[2.20727665,\, 1.8120117 ]$. How did you compute the value for $x(2)=4.04$?